# java.lang.Null pointer exception in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

While running nodetool info command, I'm getting Null pointerException and Gossip active also false.
Can anyone check and let me know the resolution.

```
*cassandra-cassandra-vm0 conf$ nodetool info**
I**D                     : e5c47b97-b07f-4a20-a135-6187adeaa833
Gossip active          : false
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: false
Load                   : 1.04 GiB
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cassandra.metrics.TableMetrics$1.getValue(TableMetrics.java:181)
```

Comment: Cassandra@cassandra-vm0 conf  nodetool status
Datacenter: ABDC
===============================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address   Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.4.2.51  44.82 GiB  16           100.0%            null                                  RAC1
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address   Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID  Rack
?N  10.4.2.61 ?          16           100.0%            null     r1

Comment: Could you add the version please.

Comment: Hi Andrew,
3.11.16

Answer (score 1):

Gossip and Native Protocol down can be caused by multiple things. I would start by checking the following 2 scenarios:

- The node was drained using `nodetool drain` - In this case, restarting it should resolve the issue.
- The storage service stopped due to a disk or commit log failure - By default Cassandra stops the service but keeps the daemon running as per the default settings (stop) for [`disk_failure_policy`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#disk_failure_policy) and [`commit_failure_policy`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#commit_failure_policy) in **cassandra.yaml**. If this is the case you should be able to confirm it by looking for **ERROR** messages in the **system.log** archives. A restart may or not resolve the problem depending on the persistence of the failure cause.